# Select date intersection

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this table

```
+------+--------+-------------------------+
|  id  | amount | start_date | end_date   |
|   10 |     10 | 2012-01-15 | 2012-01-20 |
|   10 |     12 | 2012-01-14 | 2012-01-15 |
|   10 |     22 | 2012-01-15 | 2012-01-16 |
+------+--------+-------------------------+
```

i'd wish to find the sum between a given interval.

**Example:**

start date: 2012-01-13
end date: 2012-01-18
sum(amount) = 44.

start date: 2012-01-18
end date: 2012-01-21
sum(amount) = 10

is that possible with a single query?
is that possible at all?

**EDIT**
the logic behind is that if the intevarls (given one and inside the table) overlaps, i should get the row.

Comment: Anything's possible if you believe!  Actually, could you please go into more detail here?  The request _sounds_ like you're going for an _inclusive_ set, but the examples show otherwise.

Comment: Who downvoted, and why???  Without a comment as to why, what do you expect to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM TableX
WHERE start_date <= @EndDate
  AND @StartDate <= end_date
```

where `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` are the dates you want to check between.

Comment: +1 : This is absolutely correct.  But I'd add something extra to it.  If you have an index on `start_date, end_date`, you only actually benefit from the `start_date` portion.  And on that you're only specifying `start_date <= @endDate`.  If you know the longest period that exists in your table, you can then add `AND start_date >= @startDate - (longestPeriod)`.  In large datasets this can massively reduce the number of records being checked.  This has lead me to enforce maximum durations in this type of schema, and then have multiple records to represent longer periods.

Comment: i already tried this solution and it didn't work.. do you know why? i forgot to quote dates! me dumb... :)

Comment: @Dems: Nice. This kind of two (or more) range conditions are always hard to optimize. I guess that adding also `AND (@StartDate-longestPeriod) <= end_date` might help too.

Comment: @ypercube: Probably not much, at lest if the index is `(start_date, end_date)`.  For any given start_date there are often very few different end_dates, so it'll probably just scan them any way.  Effectively with a compound index, and for a chosen range of `start_date`, the `end_date`field may as well be in random order. With two simple indexes on (start_date) and (end_date), you may get an index merge and that may yield a small benefit, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM table WHERE start_date > '2012-01-13' AND end_date < '2012-01-18'

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do:

```
select sum(amount) from my_dates where start_date >= '2012-01-13' and end_date <= '2012-01-18'
```

Gives you 34. If you want to get 44 you'd do:

```
select sum(amount) from my_dates where start_date >= '2012-01-13' and end_date <= '2012-01-20'
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) as TotalAmount
FROM `tableName`
WHERE (start_date >= '2012-01-13 00:00:00'
           AND
       end_date <= '2012-01-18 23:59:59')
```